# Including C++ sources in a Haskell project

Tags: c++, haskell, cabal

I'm trying to make a data structure that will be exposed in Haskell, but implemented in C++. So far I've implemented it in a `.cpp` file, declared all the functions I need as `extern "C"` and added the source file to the `c-sources` field in the `.cabal` file. When I build the project (in this case with `stack build`) it seems to build fine.

I know it's doing *something* to the C++ file because it doesn't compile if there are errors.

I've yet to try running the project because it's a library and so far it doesn't have anything "runnable" written, but the repl doesn't seem to work.

When I try running it (`stack repl` in this case) I get a missing symbol error with some mangled name that may or may not be refer to a name in my file.

```
unknown symbol `_ZdlPv'
linking extra libraries/objects failed
```

How can I fix this issue? I've had a similar problem before that I fixed by manually compiling the source into a dynamic library and then use that library in my project. I don't want to do that since it ties me to a platform and since it makes no sense that a simple C++ couldn't be compiled with the project using the tools that GHC already has. I want to be able to put this on hackage.

Is there something I'm missing? If not, is it a bug and are there plans on fixing it?

Comment: Please add the exact error message and a [mcve].

Comment: here is an example for a cabal package that contains C++ sources https://github.com/jbransen/minisat-bundle/blob/master/minisat.cabal

Comment: @Zeta This isn't that type of a question.

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42 Yeah, I think the problem I'm having is the missing `extra-libraries: stdc++`, but when I add it, it still doesn't work. Saying it can't find the library. I think this is a GHCi bug on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've managed to "fix" this for now.

I added a `extra-libraries: stdc++-6, gcc_s_seh-1` to my cabal file and now it works. No idea if this is platform independant but those libraries do get shipped with GHC when I install it through stack.